# convert index.php simple website to wordpress

Tags: php

I want to create a log file using the php. I am using the xampp server. I am receiving the broadcast data from the micro controller, I am calling python script from php to display my data on web browser.
Now i want this website to be more user friendly and more attractive. can any one tell me that how can I add some plugins to do so.

Comment: By hiring a web designer. Or, I can't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no quick way to "make it more user friendly and more attractive" other than hiring a web designer as David162795 said. You might want to just buy a wordpress theme you like, and in the theme files, add the php files you want to include (or modify the existing ones, *carefully*) and then incorporate that functionality into your front end UI. the php files shouldn't sit on the client side anyway, they should be on your server (in this case, your wordpress instance).